# Importing date value from .csv file to MySql database using LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql

In my project i need to upload the data which are stored in .csv file in to MySql database   table. One of the column in the table is **"dateTime".**

I tried to upload the data using **LOAD DATA INFILE**. But i am getting below error when i ran the script.

**Incorrect datetime value :  "23-JUN-14 01.50.00.944000000 PM"**

So my question is how i can load this type of date value to the table.

Please direct me.

Answer (score 0):

AS per mysql  for **datetime** data type of a column,

The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

So you can change the data type of that column to varchar and after loading the file, you can update the value of that column according to that data type.

for more >>

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html